# assign value to multiple variables.. when calling a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have something like this in my RSpec file (it works fine for me):

```
    before do
      @attr = attributes_for(:album)      
      post :create, album: @attr
    end
    it { expect(Album.exists?(@attr)).to be_true }
    it { expect(response).to redirect_to(assigns[:album]) }
```

Is it possible to make it without `attributes_for(:album)` in a separate line and `@attr` variable ? Or maybe even other better way..

Comment: Your question seems a bit unclear? what is your goal?

Comment: Get rid of `@attr` temp. variable. I believe it can be done more.. Ruby :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need of `before block` or `@attr` variable, you could change the example to something like this:

```
it "creates a album in the database" do
   expect { post :create, album: attributes_for(:album) }.to change(Album, :count).by(1)
end
```

Comment: yes but then how does he retrieve that `Album` in the test to make sure it was created correctly?

Comment: I saw that way somewhere too but.. is it good enough to assume that it was saved correctly ? and I have more `it` tests there so I would like to keep it in before block.

Comment: @pawel7318 Yes, it is good enough to test the record was saved correctly. And it is normal way of testing controllers create method.

Comment: @pawel7318 As for the more tests goes, lets discuss this on chat as I need to understand few things http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror